# What makes hashmaps faster?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I understand that the hashmaps use buckets and hashcodes and what not. From my experience, Java hashcodes are not small, but rather large numbers usually, so I assume it's not indexed internally. Unless the hashcode quality is poor resulting in approximately equal bucket length and amount buckets, what makes hashmaps faster than a list of name->value pairs?

Comment: Hashmaps use the hashcode of the key to access directly the bucket where the entry is stored. This is an O(1) access. If more than one element is in that bucket because of the same or similar hashcode, then you have a few more checks, but it's still way faster than iterating through a list and searching for an element.

Comment: Also: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Comment: @dunni But if the hashcodes are large numbers which would waste a lot of memory to be in an indexed array, how is it O(1)?

Comment: Because not the hashcode itself is used as the array index. The array which is inside the hashmap is a lot smaller (depending how you initialize it and how many elements it has) and the hashmap makes another calculation to calculate the real array index from the hashcode.

Comment: An int is hardly a large number these days...

Comment: @Robert It still is if you're indexing into an array. Max value is 2147483647. If you figure 32 bits per element (to store an object reference), that's about 8.5 GB. If every HashMap you used allocated an `Object[]` that big, you would definitely feel the impact, even on today's awesome hardware. (The way HashMap gets around this is by creating a _much_ smaller array, usually in the tens or hundreds of elements, and then using mod arithmetic to translate from the hashCode to elements in the array.)

Comment: Hash tables do not typically have more than like 50% empty 50% filled entries. You can easily just double the size of them, and move stuff around typically by chaining items together or putting them in the next available slot. We do not as a thing store 1:1 possible hash value to actual memory locations. That'd be crazy. It's just dynamically resized here and there when the ratio of entries is gets a bit bad because as it fills up the time to lookup the value gets a bit closer to N rather than 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question shows a distinct lack of research.  There will be literally hundreds of websites out there that explain the basic principles of hash tables.  Not to mention every introductory textbook on data structures and algorithms that is worth buying / borrowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashmaps work by mapping elements to "buckets" by using a hash function. When someone tries to insert an element, a hash code is calculated and a **modulus operation is applied to the hash code in order to get the bucket index in which the element should be inserted** (That is the reason why it doesn't matter how big the hashcode is). For example, if you have 4 buckets and your hashcode is 40, it will be inserted in the bucket 0, because 40 mod 4 is 0.

When two elements are mapped to the same bucket a "collision" occurs and usually the element is stored in a list under the same bucket.

If you try to obtain an element the key is mapped again using the hash function. If the bucket contains a list of elements, the equals() function is used in order to identify which element is the correct one (That is the reason why you must implement equals() and hashcode() to insert a custom object into a hashmap).

So, if you search for an element, and your hashmap does not have any lists on the buckets, you have a O(1) cost. The worst case would be when you have only 1 bucket and a list containing all elements in which obtaining an element would be the same as searching on a list O(N).

Comment: The OP is asking a junior level question, so perhaps the point should be made that order-1 says _nothing_ about execution speed in absolute terms.  An O(1) algorithm might take 8 years to complete, and remain an O(1).  It's use is in contrasting algorithms over similar goals and _specific_ techniques.

Answer (score 3):

I looked in the Java implementation and found it does a bitwise and akin to a modulus, which makes a lot of sense to reduce array size. This allows the O(1) access that makes HashMaps nice.